# Having trouble figuring out how do l combine relations in CSV in 1 run

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, csv

### acquisitions table

| id | acquisition_id | acquiring_id | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | c:11 | c:4 | 1000000000 |
| 2 | c:134 | c:4 | 2300000000 |

### objects table

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| c:11 | Instagram |
| c:134 | Oculus VR |
| c:4 | Facebook |

### results table

| parent company | acquired startup | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Facebook | Instagram | 1000000000 |
| Facebook | Oculus VR | 2300000000 |

I have `types.ts` file which lookes like:

```
export interface Acquisition {
  id: string
  acquisition_id: string
  acquiring_id: string
  price: string
}

export interface Acquisition2 {
  id: string
  acquisition_id: string
  parent_company: string
  price: string
}

export interface Object {
  id: string
  name: string
}
```

And my `index.ts` file looks like:

```
const fs = require('fs')
const fastcsv = require('fast-csv')
const neatCsv = require('neat-csv')

import { Acquisition, Acquisition2, Object } from './types'

const resultsCSV: Array<{
  parent_company?: string
  acquired_startup?: string
  price?: string
}> = []

const writeResultsCSV = (csv: typeof resultsCSV) => {
  fastcsv
    .write(csv, { headers: true })
    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./output/acquisitions.csv')) // create `output` folder manually
}

const firstRun = async () => {
  const acquisitions: Acquisition[] = await neatCsv(
    fs.createReadStream('./sample/acquisitions.csv')
  )
  const objects: Object[] = await neatCsv(
    fs.createReadStream('./sample/objects.csv')
  )

  for (let object of objects) {
    for (let acquisition of acquisitions) {
      if (object.id === acquisition.acquiring_id) {
        const data = {
          id: acquisition.id,
          acquisition_id: acquisition.acquisition_id,
          price: acquisition.price,
          parent_company: object.name,
        }
        resultsCSV.push(data)
      }
    }
  }

  writeResultsCSV(resultsCSV)
}

const secondRun = async () => {
  const acquisitions: Acquisition2[] = await neatCsv(
    fs.createReadStream('./output/acquisitions.csv')
  )
  const objects: Object[] = await neatCsv(
    fs.createReadStream('./sample/objects.csv')
  )

  for (let object of objects) {
    for (let acquisition of acquisitions) {
      if (object.id === acquisition.acquisition_id) {
        const data = {
          parent_company: acquisition.parent_company,
          acquired_startup: object.name,
          price: acquisition.price,
        }
        resultsCSV.push(data)
      }
    }
  }

  writeResultsCSV(resultsCSV)
}

const main = () => {
  // firstRun()
  secondRun()
}

main()
```

Now this works but I have to comment `secondRun()` on my first run & comment `firstRun()` on my second run.

How can I do this in a single operation? This is probably very simple but I am tired of banging my head against it for the last 2 days :(

Here's the Github repo if anyone wants to take a stab → https://github.com/deadcoder0904/combine-csv-startup-acquisitions-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Someone sent a Pull Request](https://github.com/deadcoder0904/combine-csv-startup-acquisitions-data/pull/1) on my repo & I found a simpler solution:

```
const fs = require('fs')
const fastcsv = require('fast-csv')
const neatCsv = require('neat-csv')

import { Acquisition, Object } from './types'

const resultsCSV: Array<{
  parent_company?: string
  acquired_startup?: string
  price?: string
}> = []

const writeResultsCSV = (csv: typeof resultsCSV) => {
  fastcsv
    .write(csv, { headers: true })
    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./output/acquisitions.csv')) // create `output` folder manually
}

const main = async () => {
  const acquisitions: Acquisition[] = await neatCsv(
    fs.createReadStream('./sample/acquisitions.csv')
  )
  const objects: Object[] = await neatCsv(
    fs.createReadStream('./sample/objects.csv')
  )

  acquisitions.forEach((acquisition) => {
    const parent_company = objects.find((o) => o.id == acquisition.acquiring_id)
    const acquired_startup = objects.find(
      (o) => o.id == acquisition.acquisition_id
    )
    const data = {
      parent_company: parent_company.name,
      acquired_startup: acquired_startup.name,
      price: acquisition.price,
    }
    resultsCSV.push(data)

    writeResultsCSV(resultsCSV)
  })
}

main()
```